Potential Optimization or Bug in UINavigationController Push Operation in iOS 18
Issue Description:
In iOS 18, when setting the root view controller of a UINavigationController and immediately pushing another view controller, the root view controller's lifecycle methods, such as viewDidLoad(), are not called as expected. This issue does not occur in previous iOS versions. There is no mention of this behavior in the iOS 18 release notes, and it is causing significant issues in our application.
Steps to Reproduce:
Set the root view controller of a UINavigationController.
Immediately push another view controller.
Observe that the root view controller's lifecycle methods, such as viewDidLoad(), are not called.
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("HomeViewController viewDidLoad")
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("SecondViewController viewDidLoad")
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        let home = HomeViewController()
        let rootNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: home)
        
        window?.rootViewController = rootNav
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        home.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
        
        return true
    }
}

Expected Behavior:
The root view controller's lifecycle methods, such as viewDidLoad(), should be called when setting it as the root view controller of a UINavigationController.
Actual Behavior:
In iOS 18, the root view controller's lifecycle methods are not called when it is set as the root view controller and another view controller is immediately pushed.
Impact:
This issue affects the proper initialization and setup of the root view controller, causing significant disruptions in our application's workflow.

The behavior you are noting is correct. The second view controller is being pushed so soon that the home view controller's view is never going to appear. Thus, it doesn't need to be loaded. And a view controller's view, in the normal course of things, is loaded lazily, on demand; here, there is no demand for it, so it is not loaded.
One solution is to ask yourself whether viewDidLoad was the right place for the preparations you are making. Perhaps they could be made in the home view controller's initializer instead, or in some other prepare-type method that you can call.
Another solution is simply to call loadViewIfNeeded() on the home view controller before proceeding to create and push the second view controller. Now there is a demand, because you are making that demand, and so the view will be loaded and viewDidLoad will be called.

Thank you for your answer.,The main thing is that only IOS18 can reproduce.,I understand that he did the memory optimization on this side.,Load on demand.,This should be a good thing.,But the official didn't put forward a description of the optimization.,This bothers me.,I need to be able to prove why only IOS18 has this problem.

No, I you don't need to be able to do that, because it's not a "problem". Apple often makes unannounced changes between major system version, and this can cause code to stop working — especially bad code. Here, your code was always wrong - it made a wrong assumption. Now that wrong assumption is exposed, that's all. But the fixes I have suggested will work on all systems, and are what you should always have been doing, so there's no difficulty.
